# "int main (vooid)"? How does that work?

Tags: c, syntax, program-entry-point

I recently had to type in a small C test program and, in the process, I made a spelling mistake in the main function by accidentally using `vooid` instead of `void`.

And yet it still worked.

Reducing it down to its smallest complete version, I ended up with:

```
int main (vooid) {
    return 42;
}
```

This does *indeed* compile (`gcc -Wall -o myprog myprog.c`) and, when run, it returns 42.

How exactly is this valid code?

---

Here's a transcript cut and pasted from my `bash` shell to show what I'm doing:

```
pax$ cat qq.c
int main (vooid) {
    return 42;
}

pax$ rm qq ; gcc -Wall -o qq qq.c ; ./qq

pax$ echo $?
42
```

Comment: By defining main with a single `int` parameter, you invoke **Undefined Behaviour**. Anything can happen :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about the UB, @pmg. ISO specifically allows for other possibilities of `main` from the standard two canonical ones. For portability, you should use one of those two but I don't think UB applies here.

Comment: Hmm: in a hosted environment `main` must have one of the 2 canonical forms (2.1.2.2). But you're right @pax, in a free-standing environment, the identifier `main` is in no way special: if used as a function it can be of any type and have any number of parameters of any type.

Comment: In C99, freestanding is totally implementation defined. For hosted, section 5.1.2.2.1 states at the end "or in some other implementation-defined manner" so it requires, at a minimum, the two canonical forms but can have others as well (this would allow the UNIXy `int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);` to be conforming).

Answer (score 219, accepted):

It's simply using the "old-style" function-declaration syntax; you're implicitly declaring an `int` parameter called `vooid`.

Comment: This seems to be the case.  If you add "vooid=42; return vooid;" to main, you also get a return value of 42.

Comment: Aargghh, you're right. If I add `-std=c99`, I get `qq.c:1: warning: type of 'vooid' defaults to 'int'`.

Answer (score 70):

It's valid code, because myprog.c contains:

```
int main (vooid) // vooid is of type int, allowed, and an alias for argc
{     
  return 42; // The answer to the Ultimate Question
}
```

`vooid` contains one plus the number of arguments passed (i.e., `argc`). So, in effect all you've done is to rename `argc` to `vooid`.

Comment: If you do "return vooid;" instead, it does indeed give 1 + num. of args.

Comment: @Jeff, the name of the program is counted as an arguement, hence the+1

Answer (score 23):

In C, the default type for a function argument is `int`. So, your program is treating the word `vooid` as `int main(int vooid)`, which is perfectly valid code.

Answer (score 20):

It is only `gcc -std=c89 -Wall -o qq qq.c` and `gcc -std=gnu89 -Wall -o qq qq.c` don't emit a warning.  All the other standards emit a warning about implicit type `int` for `vooid`.

`int main(chart)` behaves the same way as does `int main (vooid)`.

`return vooid;` returns the number of command line arguments.

I tested with gcc 4.4.5 on Debian testing system.