# Untyped arguments in main

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“int main (vooid)”? How does that work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987415/int-main-vooid-how-does-that-work)

```
main(a,b,c)
{
    a=1;
    b=2;
    c=3;
    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
}
```

How three Integer arguments `a`,`b`,`c` are possible inside main, as we know that the second formal parameter has to be a pointer to a pointer to a character?

Answer (score 3):

Argument parameters are implicitly `int`, unless you specify otherwise.

`main` is only required to be `main(void)` or `main(int, char **)` on a *hosted* platform (i.e., running under an OS, basically).  In a *freestanding* implementation, the prototype for `main` is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is ***deprecated*** in C. Just don't use it

Answer (score -2):

a) pointers are (almost always) ints
b) some environments, including windows allow three parameters.

**edit:** Recognised pointers are not always ints.

Comment: No they are not ints, they can be ints, but most definately do not have to be.

Comment: @wich: I'll take it even further.  They are *never* ints, they just may be the same size as ints.

Comment: What's the difference between being an int, and being indistinguishable from an int? This isn't a high-level language where all representations are numinous.

Comment: @Marcin: Saying that "a pointer is normally an int" is as meaningful as saying "a float is normally an int".

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: A specious analogy if ever I saw one. The behaviour of float and int under arithmetic operations is different, even if their length is the same. By contrast, casting a pointer to an int (assuming they are the same length), and performing arithmetic will result in exactly the same results as if no cast had occurred.

Comment: @Marcin: Firstly, that's not entirely true (although I accept the point you're trying to make!).  Secondly, why not simply rephrase your answer *correctly*: "Pointers are (almost always) the same size as ints"?  Then everybody would be happy (apart from people disputing the claim that they're almost always the same size...)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Because my point is that there is almost no scope for borkage to occur by declaring pointer parameters as ints (except the obvious that you forget what you're pointing to).