# Program crashes malloc/free, C

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int tablou(n)
{
    int *buffer, i=0;
    buffer=(int*)malloc(n+1);
    if (buffer==NULL) exit(1);
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
        buffer[i]=i;
    printf ("%d ", buffer[i]);
    }
    //free(buffer);
    //printf("%d ", n);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("nr of elements:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    tablou(n);
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it crashes at line 14:

```
free(buffer);
```

if I don't free the memory, the program gives an error after printing Hello world!
if I free the memory, it gives an error before that.

Comment: [Thou shalt not cast the result of malloc in C.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: is `int tablou(n)` correct and I missing something?

Comment: yes. it's a function

Comment: @ClockWork it's lacking the parameter type. Is it because you retyped your code? Don't retype your code when posting, I see that you missed the type of the parameter `n`, copy and paste your code so the problem remains with it.

Comment: @ClockWork I mean writing `n` without a type in function signature?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy , You need the type before `n`. But some compilers defaults to `int` if no type was specified,IIRC.

Comment: @CoolGuy Never heard of that.

Comment: `int tablou(int n)`?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy [`int main(vooid)`? How does that work?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4987415/int-main-vooid-how-does-that-work)

Comment: it works both ways. why?

Comment: @ClockWork do you even ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `malloc` allocates space in bytes, and one integer is more than 1 byte wide, this

```
buffer = (int*)malloc(n+1);
```

should be

```
buffer = malloc((n+1) * sizeof(int));
```

You should allocate space for `n + 1` integers. So you must multiply it by the size of the type.

A cleaner and more maintainable way to do it would be

```
buffer = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(*buffer));
```

Comment: I'm wondering - how will the compiler understand how much data it should free with `free()` if the amount given in `malloc()` is dynamic?

Comment: @Angivare that's a fair question to ask here.  But probably not *right here*.

Comment: @Angivare The compiler doesn't. `malloc` keeps the number somewhere (usually at the addresses that come before the one it gives you) and `free` finds that number.

Comment: @Angivare The compiler has nothing to do with it, the compiler isn't freeing any memory. The library code inside `free()` is doing that. Remember that `free()` is just a function, it's not part of the compiler. And the library does get the address of the memory to free, so it "just" has to have a way to associate that with the allocation size. That can be made in many, many ways.

Comment: @Anigivare , Read the last part of [dasblinkenlight's answer here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27675864/how-are-zero-length-arrays-in-a-structure-useful)

Comment: @Angivare From the site's C FAQ: [How does free know how much to free?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518711/how-does-free-know-how-much-to-free)